# Pass an Object with Intent using AlarmManager - receiver getting null object

Tags: android, alarmmanager, serializable

Hi I am trying to attach an Object while set AlarmManager by using the below code,

```
try {

           int when = (int)testDate.getTime();

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(mEventService, AlarmReceiver.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(Contants.NOTIFICATION_DATA, (Serializable) event);
            intent1.putExtras(bundle);

            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mEventService, (int)when, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //192837

            // Get the AlarmManager service
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) mEventService.getSystemService(mEventService.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, sender);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In the Receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Event event = (Event) intent.getSerializableExtra(Contants.NOTIFICATION_DATA);
    }
}
```

In the 'onReceive' the getSerializableExtra data is null. But, when I pass a **String value** instead of an object it is working fine.
Kindly help me to find out the issue.

Comment: `Event` is your custom class? If so then it must be implements by `Serializable`. Must check that `event` should not `null`

Comment: @Piyush: I am serializing'(Serializable) event'  and the event is not a null objct.

Answer (score 4):

Using custom `Parcelable` and `Serializable` classes with extras in a `PendingIntent` [will break things like `AlarmManager` on Android 7.0+](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html).